# TableView and UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my application, I am using `UITableView`. Now I can change the size of the table view as whatever I want. But If I add one `UINavingationController` with that table view controller, the size of the table view will be changed to full screen automatically. But I want the table view size should be at the old custom size. Please check my code here. And also If I comment the last line it works correctly. Please help me to solve this problem.

UITableViewController *directoryViewController = [[DirectoryViewController alloc] init];

```
UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 150)];
table.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
directoryViewController.tableView = table;
directoryViewController.view = table;
[explorer addSubview:directoryViewController.view];

directoryNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:directoryViewController];
[explorer addSubview:directoryNavigationController.view];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a standard UIViewController if you're looking for more control over the table portion. UITableViewController makes some assumptions that you might not like.